# Vue: `global.Symbol` is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, npm, babeljs

Have been banging my head with this for over 12 hours. This is a Vue project that compiles and launches fine but throws the following error when trying to load the page:

```
well-known-symbol.js:16 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at hasOwn (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/core-js/internals/well-known-symbol.js.module.exports (well-known-symbol.js:16:26)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/internals/to-primitive.js (to-primitive.js:10:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:853:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/internals/to-property-key.js (to-property-key.js:1:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:853:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.constructor.js (es.symbol.constructor.js:14:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:853:1)
push../node_modules/core-js/internals/well-known-symbol.js.module.exports   @   well-known-symbol.js:16
./node_modules/core-js/internals/to-primitive.js    @   to-primitive.js:10
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/core-js/internals/to-property-key.js @   to-property-key.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.constructor.js @   es.symbol.constructor.js:14
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.js @   es.symbol.js:2
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js @   chunk-vendors.js:689
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js    @   amd-options.js:2
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/core-js/internals/global.js  @   chunk-vendors.js:6147
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/core-js/internals/export.js  @   export.js:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js    @   es.error.cause.js:2
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js    @   chunk-vendors.js:46948
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
fn  @   bootstrap:150
1   @   app.js:1375
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:853
checkDeferredModules    @   bootstrap:45
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:993
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:993
```

I'm not a JS-specialist, but using my limited browser-debugging skill I have found that the problem lies in `well-known-symbol.js`, which looks like this:

```
var global = require('../internals/global');
var shared = require('../internals/shared');
var hasOwn = require('../internals/has-own-property');
var uid = require('../internals/uid');
var NATIVE_SYMBOL = require('../internals/native-symbol');
var USE_SYMBOL_AS_UID = require('../internals/use-symbol-as-uid');

var WellKnownSymbolsStore = shared('wks');
var Symbol = global.Symbol;
var symbolFor = Symbol && Symbol['for'];
var createWellKnownSymbol = USE_SYMBOL_AS_UID ? Symbol : Symbol && Symbol.withoutSetter || uid;

module.exports = function (name) {
  if (!hasOwn(WellKnownSymbolsStore, name) || !(NATIVE_SYMBOL || typeof WellKnownSymbolsStore[name] == 'string')) {
    var description = 'Symbol.' + name;
    if (NATIVE_SYMBOL && hasOwn(Symbol, name)) {
      WellKnownSymbolsStore[name] = Symbol[name];
    } else if (USE_SYMBOL_AS_UID && symbolFor) {
      WellKnownSymbolsStore[name] = symbolFor(description);
    } else {
      WellKnownSymbolsStore[name] = createWellKnownSymbol(description);
    }
  } return WellKnownSymbolsStore[name];
};
```

Cause of the exception is that `global.Symbol` is `undefined` at line 9, which causes the exception at line 16.

Have gone through numerous SO posts and Github issues; none of the solutions have worked so far. Other people have reported this issue, but only for IE11, whereas in my case I'm getting this in latest Edge.(`101.0.1210.53 (Official build) (64-bit)`).

Worst part is that this project was building and running perfectly fine about a couple of months ago. Then I had to pause working on it. Now after two months, I just opened the last working copy and bammm... it throws the above error.

Simple fixes like `npm install`, deleting `node_modules` etc. have not worked either.

Comment: Deps were likely botched in some way.  A quick search for "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" "well-known-symbol" suggests that the problem is in the combination of webpack, babel and core-js versions. It depends a lot on what happened with your lock file. There are ways in which npm lock could be unintentionally broken. you need to revert deps to the point the error doesn't occur anymore and proceed from there. It's suggested that Vue CLI/Webpack need to be upgraded to 5, but it depends on your case if it's applicable

Comment: @EstusFlask: Thanks. i'll try to revert to a previous version, though as I said, my working copy was in good state where I left it 2 months ago.  About upgrading to Webpack 5, I have tried that as well, but that also fails and throws error about some dependency. BTW, my `package-lock.json` is fortunately under source control; good that I opted for checking it in, when some people were suggesting otherwise.

Comment: Yes, lock file should never be opted out, it can only be deleted and regenerated when deps conflict is a deadend (probably can be tried here). Another problem with npm is that they can handle it differently between versions. npm 7 and 8 are fully compatible afaik, but npm 6 will result in a different set of deps and will break lock file, and vice versa. If you changed npm recently, this needs to be taken into account when lock file changes are reverted

Comment: @EstusFlask: Just wanted to say thanks. Restoring old `package-lock.json` did the trick for me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.